# React LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying through a click function in React to increase a global counter and keep the increased counter in localStorage. Currently its only working when you're on the same page and when you pass the data to another page. But as soon as you click back and increment the counter again, the data is reset starting from zero instead of the stored counter. if this makes sense. Help! how can i count from the stored data instead of from the state data?

Here's the code:

```
 handleIncrement = counter => {
    const courses = [...this.state.courses]; //clones new arrays of counters
    const index = courses.indexOf(counter); // gets obj index that we receive as parameter
    courses[index] = {...counter}; //sets current index to new cloned counter
    courses[index].value++; //increments current index
    //console.log(this.state.counters[index]);
    let value = this.state.courses[0].value + this.state.courses[1].value + this.state.courses[2].value + this.state.courses[3].value +  this.state.courses[4].value + this.state.courses[5].value
    let name1 = this.state.courses[0].name
    localStorage.setItem("list", value );
    this.setState({courses}); //updates the view
};
```

Comment: It sounds like you want [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage)

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look on how to implement.

Comment: Here's what you can do, begin the counter, once you're done/leave page save that number to the local storage using the methods in AsyncStorage. When you open that page, check the AsyncStorage to see if that number exists, pull it out if it does, set it to 0 if it doesn't. Just save it on `componentWillUnmount()` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you are launching handleIncrement, you are setting your localStorage to the value "value". "value" is coming from your state:

```
    let value = this.state.courses[0].value + this.state.courses[1].value + this.state.courses[2].value + this.state.courses[3].value +  this.state.courses[4].value + this.state.courses[5].value
```

Every time you are reloading, it seems your state is starting from zero again. And every time you are launching handleIncrement, you are giving your localStorage a new value:

```
    localStorage.setItem("list", value );
```

Remember your should at some point retrieve the value from your localStorage as such:

```
    const savedValue = localStorage.getItem("list");
```

Answer (score 0):

I just redid the logic of the click event and it worked. Here's my solution:

handleIncrement = counter => {
  if (localStorage.getItem("list") === null) {

```
  localStorage.getItem("list" );

}else{
  const courses = [...this.state.courses]; //clones new arrays of counters
  const index = courses.indexOf(counter); // gets obj index that we receive as parameter
  courses[index] = {...counter}; //sets current index to new cloned counter

  courses[index].value++; //increments current index
  //console.log(this.state.counters[index]);
  let allcookies = Number(localStorage.getItem('list')) + 1
  localStorage.setItem("list", allcookies );


  this.setState({courses}); //updates the view
   //let name1 = this.state.courses[0].name;

}
```

};